# Dynamic module name

Tags: haskell, module

I want to do something like this in Haskell, but the compiler is not letting me.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

```
-- both modules export function named "hello"
-- and I want to run it in every module
import qualified MyMod as M1
import qualified MyAnotherMod as M2

runmodules = map (\m -> m.hello) [M1, M2]
```

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve? Since the function name is known (hello), why not just put the functions into a list `[M1.hello, M2.hello]` and do something with that list? I guess you could somehow get by with TemplateHaskell, but it might be overly complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can quote a qualified name prefix like that in template haskell, and the `hello` identifier isn't in scope, so you might have to fall back to programming with strings.

```
module ModuleParamsTH where
import Language.Haskell.TH

getAll :: String -> [String] -> ExpQ
getAll valueName moduleNames = 
  listE $ map (varE . mkName . (++ suffix)) moduleNames
  where suffix = "." ++ valueName
```

which can then be used like so,

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import ModuleParamsTH
import qualified ModuleParamsM1 as M1
import qualified ModuleParamsM2 as M2

runmodules = $(getAll "hello" ["M1", "M2"])
```

However, I would not do all this. You could just write `[M1.hello, M2.hello]` or use a type class to abstract over implementations.

Answer (score 8):

Modules in Haskell are not even remotely first-class entities in the ways this would require, I'm afraid.

However, as bzn commented, [Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell) can be used for problems like this. The result can be a bit clumsy, but if you really need some quick metaprogramming hacks it's not a bad choice. I'm not really an expert with TH, but what you want is pretty simple, with one catch: Neither "ambiguous identifiers" nor "module names" can be captured or quoted in any way, as far as I know, so you'll have to put them in strings given as arguments to the TH function.

Here's a quick and dirty, minimal example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module MapModuleTH where

import Language.Haskell.TH

mapQual :: [String] -> String -> ExpQ
mapQual ms n = listE $ map (\m -> varE . mkName $ m ++ "." ++ n) ms

mapMQual :: [String] -> String -> ExpQ
mapMQual ms n = appE (varE 'sequence) $ listE $ map (\m -> varE . mkName $ m ++ "." ++ n) ms
```

You phrased things as "running the function" which sounds more like doing a bunch of `IO` actions, not just collecting a list of stuff, so I added a variant that also sequences the result.

Note that, despite the use of strings here, this *is* still statically typed--if the qualified names don't exist, or the types don't match up, you'll get the expected compile-time error just as if you'd written everything out by hand.

Here's a quick example of using it. Given the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module MapModule where

import MapModuleTH
import qualified Test1 as T1
import qualified Test2 as T2

tests = do xs <- $(mapMQual ["T1", "T2"] "test")
           putStrLn $ "Count: " ++ show (length xs)
```

Assuming the other modules are there and define `test`, then in GHCi we can see:

```
> tests
Test 1
Test 2
Count: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Modules aren't values in Haskell. Therefore that isn't possible. What do you want to achieve?